# File is showing in use even after using file.close()

Tags: python

I am trying to send an email with the file attachment and post that it should rename and move that file to Archive Folder.
No issues with email.

```
if (exception_count != 0):
    filename= "abc.log"
    with open(filename) as file:
        try:
            sender = 'from@email.com'
            receivers='someone@email.com'
            file = open("abc.log", mode='r')

            msg = EmailMessage()
            msg["From"] = sender
            msg["Subject"] = "Subject - abc"
            msg["To"] = receivers
            msg.set_content("PFA for the Error Log File")
            msg.add_attachment(file.read(), filename=filename)

            s = smtplib.SMTP('smtp',25)
            s.send_message(msg)
        
        except:
            file.close()
        
            
now = datetime.datetime.now()
dt_string = now.strftime("%d%m%Y_")
path= r"C:\Users\username\Documents\Dev Python Scripts\Log_Archive"
shutil.move(r'C:\Users\username\Documents\Dev Python Scripts\abc.log', path + "\\" + dt_string + filename)
```

Getting error

> The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another
> process:

on `shutil.move(r'C:\Users\username\Documents\Dev Python Scripts\abc.log', path + "\\" + dt_string + filename)`

I have tried with try and final statements initially it wasn't working, Saw one similar question about file handling on Stackover flow where it was suggested to use WITH().

I appreciate any help.

**EDITED CODE:**

```
if (exception_count != 0):
    filename= "abc.log"
    with open(filename) as file:
        
            sender = 'from@email.com'
            receivers='someone@email.com'
            #file = open("abc.log", mode='r')

            msg = EmailMessage()
            msg["From"] = sender
            msg["Subject"] = "Subject - abc"
            msg["To"] = receivers
            msg.set_content("PFA for the Error Log File")
            msg.add_attachment(file.read(), filename=filename)

            s = smtplib.SMTP('smtp',25)
            s.send_message(msg)
        
            
now = datetime.datetime.now()
dt_string = now.strftime("%d%m%Y_")
path= r"C:\Users\username\Documents\Dev Python Scripts\Log_Archive"
shutil.move(r'C:\Users\username\Documents\Dev Python Scripts\abc.log', path + "\\" + dt_string + filename)
```

Comment: The whole point of `with open(...)` is that you do not need a `try` block to ensure that the file gets closed.  And why are you opening the file *again* inside the block?

Comment: I gave it a try without a `try` block also, I was getting the same error, I wanted to double proof it with the `FINAL` statement and hence used `TRY`, I know it sounds silly.

Comment: It is not only silly, but also introduces the error. `with open` is enough.

Comment: I have edited the code, error is still same.

Comment: If you have not closed your IDE since making the changes, then I would recommend rebooting IDE, and try again.

Answer (score 1):

The problem you are seeing is likely due to the fact that you are opening the file **twice** in your code.

If you have code that looks like this:

```
file = open("abc.log", mode='r')
```

then you need some code to close the file

```
file.close()
```

---

However, if you have code that looks like this:

```
with open(filename) as file:
    ...
```

then you **do not need to close the file**. It will close automatically when the program exits the `with-block`.

---

Therefore your code should look something like this:

```
filename= "abc.log"

if (exception_count != 0):
    
    with open(filename) as file:
        
            sender = 'from@email.com'
            receivers='someone@email.com'

            msg = EmailMessage()
            msg["From"] = sender
            msg["Subject"] = "Subject - abc"
            msg["To"] = receivers
            msg.set_content("PFA for the Error Log File")
            msg.add_attachment(file.read(), filename=filename)

            s = smtplib.SMTP('smtp',25)
            s.send_message(msg)
        
            
now = datetime.datetime.now()
dt_string = now.strftime("%d%m%Y_")
path= r"C:\Users\username\Documents\Dev Python Scripts\Log_Archive"
shutil.move(r'C:\Users\username\Documents\Dev Python Scripts\abc.log', path + "\\" + dt_string + filename)
```

### Note

- I have removed the `file = open("abc.log", mode='r')` from inside of the `with-block`
- also worth **rebooting IDE** once you make the changes just in case the open files (or non-closed files) are still in memory.

Comment: Thank you Scottc for your reply, You are right. Per the last suggestion by @cpt.hook, I made the same change, "Code available in the edited section". I am still getting the same error.

Comment: Please reboot the IDE, and try again - let me know if it still persists.

Comment: Sure, going to do it.